# Postgresql : how can i get desired output as described below

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `Box` :

Box contains the following items :

```
1. pen

2. pencil

3. scale

4. eraser

5. sharpener
```

The actual table structure looks like this :

```
No        Item       quantity       bought_date
_______________________________________________

 1.        pen              3        14-12-2016

 2.     pencil             10        15-12-2016

 3.        pen              5        16-12-2016

 4.     eraser              7        16-12-2016

 5.  sharpener              6        17-12-2016

 6.     pencil              3        18-12-2016

 7.        pen              3        18-12-2016
```

***output needed:***

```
Item         Total_quantity
___________________________

Pencil                   13

Pen                      11

Eraser                    7

Sharpener                 6  

Scale                     0
___________________________

total                    37
```

Please help me with this query...

Comment: What you've done so far?.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY`, combined with `SUM`.

Comment: I got rows present in the table but i did n't got the "scale"(which is not present in the table) and i am unable to achieve "order" by count(quantity)

Comment: I tried "sum" but it is showing "error" since it is varchar. so i went for using "count" and i am getting the "total".

The only problems i had is "order by" and "including new values in the output" like "scale" shown in the output.

Comment: @saivenkatavinaypasupuleti how comes `Scale_______ 0` in expected output?

Comment: Do you have another table with all possible items (incl Scale)? If that's the case, do a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: i know it is not in the table. but, i have many tables like similar described above, each table differs with one missing item. so, i need record the missing item too in the output as null "0". @wingedpanther

Comment: How do you find missing item??

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d32a/4)?

Comment: yes i have similar issues @wingedpanther

Comment: i will try it @sagi Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t.item,sum(cast(coalese(b.quantity,'0') as integer)) as total_quantity FROM (
    SELECT 'pen' as item
    UNION
    SELECT 'pencil' as item
    UNION
    SELECT 'scale' as item
    UNION
    SELECT 'eraser' as item
    UNION
    SELECT 'sharpener' as item) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN box b
ON(t.item = b.item)
GROUP BY t.item
UNION
(SELECT 'total',sum(quantity)
FROM box)
```

I've adjusted the code according to your comments, I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer@sagi i have a doubt **Let say there is no "quantity" column in the table and pen,pencil etc items repeats multiple times which is a varchar. can u please suggest me the changes can i do in your answer.** thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select it, sum(s) s from
(
select b.item it, sum(b.qty::integer) s from box b group by b.item
union
select 'total' as item ,sum(qty::integer )total from box group by item  
) as un group by un.it;
```

Comment: What about items that don't have any quantity in box table? what about the fact the he said the quantity is a varchar?

Comment: Let say there is no "quantity" column in the table  and pen,pencil etc items repeats multiple times which is a varchar.@sagi can u please suggest me the changes can i do in your answer. thank you @sagi

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and more convenient way is:

```
with items(item_no, item_name) as (
  values
    (1, 'pen'),
    (2, 'pencil'),
    (3, 'scale'),
    (4, 'eraser'),
    (5, 'sharpener')
  )
select
  items.item_name,
  coalesce(sum(box.quantity::int), 0) as total_quantity
from
  items
    left join box on (box.item = items.item_name)
group by
  items.item_name

union all

select
  'total',
  coalesce(sum(box.quantity::int), 0)
from
  box
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer@Abelisto  
i have a doubt
**Let say there is no "quantity" column in the table and pen,pencil etc items repeats multiple times which is a varchar. can u please suggest me the changes can i do in your answer. thank you**

Comment: @saivenkatavinaypasupuleti As I understand, for 10 pencils you have 10 rows in your table instead of one row and field `quantity`? If so then replace `sum(box.quantity::int)` to `count(1)`.

Comment: yeah you are right i will replace and try it. thank you

Comment: @saivenkatavinaypasupuleti Keep in mind that I just propose more clean variant specific for Postgres syntax of the sagi's answer which you are already accepted :)

Comment: Sure @ Abelisto, but your answer helped me a lot, for the doubt i asked you. It is working now, thank you so much.

Comment: @saivenkatavinaypasupuleti Nice to see it. Good luck :)

Comment: Not only you answer an hour and a half after me, you wrote the exact same answer . The only difference is that you use with instead of my select

Comment: @sagi I mentioned it in the comment above. BTW there are a bit more differences then just using `WITH` clause. And thats why I wrote my answer.